# Prove endpoints of Convergence Interval of Power Series are divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, sequence-of-function

Part a) of a question required showing that the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{} \frac{n!}{n^n}x^n$ and $\sum_{} \frac{n^n}{n!}x^n$ are e and 1/e respectively. This was fairly simple.

Part b) of the same question required showing that $a(n)=(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ is a strictly increasing sequence (whose limit is e). I was also able to get this out.

But part c) now states: Deduce from your working in a) and b) that $\sum_{} \frac{n!}{n^n}x^n$ diverges for x=e and x=-e.

I know that I am meant to substitute the values of the endpoints e and -e into the sequence. However, i have tried numerous tests - (ratio test which gave r=1) and have also been unable to get anywhere with the integral, comparison and kth term tests for divergence.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Doesn't the $n$th term go to $\infty?$

Comment: It might, it might not. Hard to tell. Even harder to prove.

Comment: Have you considered Stirling's formula?

Comment: I haven't actually learnt that yet. Interestingly though, part d of the question, allows you to assume Stirling's Formula.
I'd assume that for part c then that it's probably not required

Answer (score 1):

For $n\geq2,$ wwe have $$\log{n!}=\sum_{k=2}^n{\log{k}}>\sum_{k=2}^n{\int_{k-1}^k\log{x}\mathrm{dx}}=(x\log{x}-x)|_1^n=n\log{n}-n+1$$

(The inequality $\log{k}>\int_{k-1}^k\log{x}\mathrm{dx}$ is true because $\log{x}$ is an increasing function, so on the interval $(k-1,k),\ \log{k}>\log{x}.)$

Therefore,$$
\log{n!e^n\over n^n}=\log{n!}+n-n\log{n}>(n\log{n}-n+1)+n-n\log{n}=1$$so that $${n!e^n\over n^n}>e,$$

and $\sum {n!e^n\over n^n}$ diverges, since the $n$th term  doesn't go to $0$.

Your question says that you are supposed to answer part c) based on your workings of parts a) and b), and you haven't shown those, so I don't know if you can use this answer directly, but perhaps it will help.

A more careful estimate of the integral in the first line is an essential part of the derivation of Stirling's approximation.

Comment: For part a, i found where the series absolutely converges to determine teh radius of convergence. For part b, i showed that it was an increasing function based off Cauchy's Inequality.
Part c tells us to deduce from parts a and b so i agree this method you've shown may not be what's required. However, can you explain how you obtained the inequality in the first line? (from sum of logk to the logx integral)

Comment: @raz999 I added an explanation to my answer.